# rsync delete folders from destination if does not exists in source

Tags: backup, rsync

Whilst I take a backup I want to delete from the Hard disk that I store the backup folders that does not exists on source in order to keep my backup minimum.

In the source I have lots of junk files and I do not want to backup them such as development purpoce docker volumes.

Do you know what parameter does that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
rsync -avhH --delete /src/dir /dest/dir/
```

That will delete any files in the destination directory on that don't exist in the source directory.

As for the rest of the switches `a` uses archive mode, `v` makes it verbose so that you can see what's happening during the process, `h` makes any numbers human-readable, and `H` preserves hard links.

Comment: In case that I keep a list of files to backup in a text file how I can force to delete the files that is not in this file as well?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas You would have to manually delete them from the backup itself. `rsync --delete` only deletes them if they don't exist in the source directory.